# Source or locally-built dependencies in project.json

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dnx

I'm trying to get a development environment set up for ASP.NET MVC 6 (i.e., I'd like to be able to debug and write PRs for MVC itself) using a sample application (using a project similar to the starter template), and I'm unclear on how to create the references using the dependencies section in `project.json`.  Here's mine:

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta3"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": { },
        "aspnetcore50": { }
    },
    "bundleExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.kproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ]
}
```

I think this is pretty much what you get out of the box when you build an MVC app.  But I want to replace the reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` 6.0.0-beta3 with something local - whether a locally build nupkg or a project file I'm not sure.  I've looked at the [explanation of project.json on the Aspnet wiki](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file) and didn't find anything helpful, and the explanation of how kpm (folded into dnx for beta4 and beyond, right?) resolves versions seems focused on the version graph rather than where the things come from.

What I have right now is the Mvc repo with the binaries/nupkgs built, I just don't know what to put in the dependencies section.

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "Microsoft.Aspet.Mvc": ???
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dependencies section in `project.json` stays the same as when referencing packages. What you need to change is in the `global.json` file. You need to tell the runtime where the code is and it will replace any package with its source code, if it finds it:

```
{
  "sources": [
    "src",
    "test",
    "d:/debug/mvc/src"
  ]
}
```

For more details take look at my article about debugging ASP.NET 5 framework code: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/06/debugging-asp-net-5-framework-code-using-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  Makes perfect sense.

Comment: I tried this and got it to "work" - in the sense that VS recognized the source directory I pointed to and loaded up all the MVC projects into the solution just like you said would happen in your blog, but the references are all broken.  For now, I wanted to reverse the process.  I commented out the line in global.json, but the projects remain and VS2015 CTP hangs if I try to remove the Mvc projects.  Is this a known issue?

Comment: So, does this work the same way if building using the command line tools?  I tried this trick and then ran `dnu restore`, and it doesn't appear to have done anything (I checked the lock file and the references look the same as before...).

Comment: Is it possible to share the project and the output of `dnu restore`?

Comment: Perhaps, but it's unnecessary now; I realized late last night that I had misspelt the path.  Code wasn't happy about it, but it worked.